# Wordpress Multiple Post Thumbnails Woocommerce & WPML

Tags: post, woocommerce, thumbnails, wpml

I am using WPML plugin for translating woocommerce products. In the original language the secondary image is visible but when I view the translated product page it disappeared. How to solve this problem?
I am calling the secondary image in product-image.php file of the woocommerce templete. Bellow is the code:

```
<?php $secondary_image_url = ultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(),'secondary-image');$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );echo "    <ul class='woocommerce-thumbnail-open'>
    <li class='large-woocommerce'>LARGE:</li>
    <li class='openthumbnail' link='".$thumbnail."'>FRONT</li>
    <li class='openthumbnail' link='".$secondary_image_url."'>BACK</li>
</ul>";?>
```

The featured image is working fine.

Comment: Have you tried contacting WPML support?

Comment: What are the different WPML components plugins enabled in wordpress?

Comment: Translation management, string translation, WooCommerce Multilingual, WPML Media , WP menus SYNC, taxonomy translation